# Show me your ID(E)!

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, workflow, real-time, development-environment

I often work on very small pieces of code, on the order of max 100 lines, especially in scenarios when I learn something new and just play with the code, or when I debug.

Because I frequently change code and want to see how that changes the contents of my variables and output, it is tedious to *either*

1) hit the debug button, wait for the debugger to start (in my case I use PyCharm as an IDE) and then inspect the output

*or*

2) insert some prints for the variables that I want to observe and compile the code (slightly faster than starting the debugger).

**To eliminate this time consuming workflow, where I constantly hit the compile or debug button every few seconds, is there an IDE where I can set a  watch to a few variables and then each time I change in my source code a single character (or, alternatively, every half a second) the IDE automatically compiles everything and I will see then new values of my variables?**

(Of course while I intermediatelychange the code the compilation will give errors, but that is ok. This feature would be a big time saver. Maybe PyCharm has it already implemented? If not, ideally I would hope for a language agnostic IDE, similar to PyCharm, where variants for Java etc. also exist. If not, since I code in Python, a Python IDE would also be great.)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that no one has tought of this feature. Is there really no such IDE out there?

Comment: Is this question python specific? In Java you can hot-reload parts of code while program is running (almost every bigger IDE support it). In other languages you can use auto-test(supported by some IDEs or CLI watchers)

Comment: @mleko This question is not Python specific. While I currently do use mainly Python and my immediate usage of it will be Python-based, I'd hope for a solution that is language agnostic, so that I use these features in e.g. C++ as well.

Comment: Then I think auto-test is what you are looking for. AFAIK there is no single tool to rule'em all, but most languages I used so far have their own tools to perform tests on code change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but PyCharm (and IntelliJ and probably others) can run tests automatically when code changes.

In the PyCharm **Run toolbar** look for **"Toggle auto-test"** button.

For example in PyCharm you can create test cases that just runs the code you're interested in and prints the variables you need. 
Then create a run configuration that runs only those tests and set it to run automatically.

For more details see [PyCharm documentation on rerunning tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rerunning-tests.html).

Answer (score 3):

The Scala plugin for IntelliJ has exactly what you need in the form of "worksheets," where every expression is automatically recompiled when its value or the value of anything it references is changed.

Since (based on your usage of PyCharm), I assume you're using Python primarily, I think [Jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/) is your best bet. Jupyter is language agnostic but began as specific to python (it was called IPython notebook for this reason).

I have not tried it, but [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html) purports to show to get Jupyter to work with PyCharm

EDIT: Here is another possibility called [vim worksheet](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/vim-worksheet); I haven't tried it, but it purports to do the same thing as Scala worksheets, but in vim, and for a number of languages, including Python.

Answer (score 1):

The python Spyder IDE (comes with Anaconda) has this feature. When you hit run, you can see all of the variables at the top right of the screen and you can click on them to see their values (this is very helpful with Numpy Arrays too!).

Answer (score 1):

If your interest is in the actual workflow improvement:

I used to program like you, looking at what my variables changed to, and design or debug my code based on such modifications, however is way to inefficient and costly to set what variables to watch over and over again and besides when if it bugs, you have to go all over again for the debugging process.

I changed my design process to better my workflow and adopted Test Driven Development (TDD), with it you can look at tools for you specific implementations or IDEs but the principles and workflow stay with you, with it you stop looking on how the variables changed and instead focus on what the functions should do, meaning faster iteration (with real time tools for testing), easier debugging and far more better, safe refactoring.

My favorite tool for it is Cucumber, and agnostic tool (for IDE or programming language) which help you test your code scenarios and at the same time documenting your features.

Hope it helps, i know its a very opinionated answer but it's an honest advices for improvement in ones workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Thonny](http://thonny.org/). It is developed by [Institute of Computer Science](http://www.cs.ut.ee/) of [University of Tartu](http://www.ut.ee/).

The 4 features which might be of help to you are below (verbatim from the website):

1. No-hassle variables.

   Once you're done with hello-worlds, select View → Variables and see how your programs and shell commands affect Python variables.
2. Simple debugger.

   Just press Ctrl+F5 instead of F5 and you can run your programs step-by-step, no breakpoints needed. Press F6 for a big step and F7 for a small step. Steps follow program structure, not just code lines.
3. Stepping through statements

   Step through expression evaluation. If you use small steps, then you can even see how Python evaluates your expressions. You can think of this light-blue box as a piece of paper where Python replaces subexpressions with their values, piece-by-piece.
   Visualization of expression evaluation
4. Faithful representation of function calls.

   Stepping into a function call opens a new window with separate local variables table and code pointer. Good understanding of how function calls work is especially important for understanding recursion.